# AlarmManeger setExact is not working

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

setExact method is not working on my project

```
Log.d("Alarm","Fire");
```

that is in AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver is not showing up after 1 minute!

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    .
    .
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            .
            .

            Calendar alarm = Calendar.getInstance();
            alarm.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            alarm.add(Calendar.MINUTE,1);

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent  pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent, 0);

            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarm.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
            .
            .
}
}
```

AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver:

```
public class AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.d("Alarm","Fire");

       }
}
```

I have tried to extend BroadcastReceiver instead of WakefulBroadcastReceiver. I also tried to set diffrenet hard coded times.  However, nothing works.

Please help

Comment: Hoping you have not missed declaring the receiver and adding the wake lock permission in manifest file.

Comment: @RickSanchez Thanks so much. Problem solved. I can't believe that I made that dumb mistake. Thanks a lot Rick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [link](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) (Scheduling Repeating Alarms) helps you. You must add

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>
<receiver android:process=":remote" android:name=".AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver"></receiver>`